# How to add bounds for a variable based on a column in dataframe?

Tags: python, variables, optimization, bounds, pyomo

model.PVtoB = Var(model.T, bounds=(0,????))

Trying to set bounds on the above variable. The bound should be dictated by a column called "Pv Generation" in the dataframe. How do I refer to the values in the PV Generation column?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is with a rule:

```
def PVtoB_bounds(m, t):
    # Use t index to extract desired lb and ub from the dataframe
    lb = DATAFRAME VALUE
    ub = DATAFRAME VALUE
    return (lb,ub)
model.PVtoB = Var(model.T, bounds=PVtoB_bounds)
```

Comment: Thank you! But the main problem that I am having here is how to add these ub and lb iteratively so it the upper bound is always changing after every 168 values (24*7) over the entire year.

Comment: Using the rule you can specify a different lb and ub value for every index in `model.T`. The rule will automatically be called once for every index in `model.T` and the value will be passed in to the `t` argument. I didn't show code for extracting specific values from your dataframe since I don't know what your data looks like but you could also do other calculations on the `t` passed in instead of reading from the dataframe (like using a mod operator).

Comment: So I have a 'PVGeneration' column which is hourly solar generation data inside the dataframe and I am trying to extract values from each hour.

Comment: Please see this new thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58669580/bounds-on-pyomo-variable-based-on-column-in-dataframe